# Is Indian Journal of Medical Research Impact Factor right?

Tags: phd, bibliometrics

I was searching for Journal Impact Factor on internet, after that I came across a website named [Journals Insights](https://www.journalsinsights.com/).

I'll like to know if the Impact Factor mentioned on the website is correct or not?
Specifically, the IF for the [Indian journal of medical research](https://www.journalsinsights.com/journals/indian-journal-of-medical-research#indian_journal_of_medical_research_impact_factor)

Answer (score 1):

I have checked the 'official' Impact Factor at Clairviate Journal Citation Reports, and yes, the 2023 value is 4.2. This is down from a high of 5.3 last year, but significantly up from values in the range of 1.2-1.5 pre-2020.

Looking at the most cited papers from the past 2 years, 20 of the top 25 are COVID-19 related, and several of the others are more general reviews of relevance to COVID-19 (respiratory illnesses, obesity). So the journal has seen a huge upswing due to these COVID-related papers, but it remains to be seen if this will persist as we move back to more normal publishing patterns.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot say whether that website is accurate. But I can say that impact factors are put out by Clarivate. So if you want to check a journals impact factor, or even verify that the journal has an impact factor at all, look at Clarivate's [Master Journal List](https://mjl.clarivate.com/home). I think some of the specific metrics (impact factor possibly included) are locked behind a subscription though. Alternatively, you can just look at the journal's home page directly. I suppose they could lie there, but that's out of your control.

Answer (score 0):

On face value, the Journals Insights is an aggregator with fairly good metrics.

---

The Journals Insights appears to be an aggregator. As to its credibility, I can not say. However, going by the listing for this ***Indian Journal of Medical Research***, it is not far off.

It listed the SJR as 0.716. On Scimago, the SJR is 0.72 with H-index of 96.

Regarding impact factor (IF), the [Journals Insights](https://www.journalsinsights.com/journals/indian-journal-of-medical-research#indian_journal_of_medical_research_scimago) says the "*Impact Factor of Indian Journal of Medical Research is 4.2 (2023)*".
However, the journal's [website](https://ijmr.icmr.org.in/ijmr/index.aspx) says "*Impact Factor® as reported in the 2022 Journal Citation Reports® (Clarivate Analytics, 2022): 5.274*".

This is similar to another [aggregator](https://academic-accelerator.com): "*Indian Journal of Medical Research is 5.274, which is just updated in 2023.*"
PS: can't vouch for this Academic accelerator as well.

[Scopus Preview](https://www.scopus.com/sourceid/14659) shows that the journal (with two previous names) and ISSN:0971-5916 has a [cite score of 5.6](https://www.scopus.com/sourceid/14659) as of May 2023.
PS: The SJR of 0.716 matches that of Journals Insights.
Likewise, the ISSN matches that of Scimago and [Journals Insights](https://www.journalsinsights.com/journals/indian-journal-of-medical-research#indian_journal_of_medical_research_details).

- Print ISSN    0971-5916
- Online ISSN   0975-9174